# Running pdftex with specific map file

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Is it possible to run `pdftex` with a specific map file that is not named `pdftex.map`? I am aware that I can specify a search path for map files using the environmentvariable `TEXFONTMAPS`, but it seems that `pdftex` only uses a map file from this path if it is called `pdftex.map`.

Some background: I am developing a font package and would like to generate a font chart using `fontchart.tex` from the build directory without the need to install the font. `pdftex` has access to all necessary files (TFM, PFB and ENC files plus the map file), but doesn't process the map file since it is not called `pdftex.map`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See documentation of pdfTeX (`pdftex-a.pdf`). You can use e.g. `\pdfmapfile` in you document. Or to quote the documentation:

> If you want to use a base map file
>   name other than pdftex.map, or change
>   its processing options through a
>   pdfTeX format, you can do this by
>   appending the `\pdfmapfile` command to
>   the `\everyjob{}` token list for the
>   -ini run, e. g.: `\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\pdfmapfile{+myspecial.map}}
>   \dump` This would always read the file
>   `myspecial.map` after the default
>   `pdftex.map` file.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the documentation, but concentrated on command line options.

Answer (score 4):

For a run-time version, this is the call from the shell

```
pdftex "\pdfmapfile{+myspecial.map}\input test"
pdflatex "\pdfmapfile{+myspecial.map}\input{test}"
```

If you say `\pdfmapfile{myspecial.map}` this will substitute completely `pdftex.map`; with `\pdfmapfile{=myspecial.map}` entries in `myspecial.map` will override those in `pdftex.map` if the font name (precisely the `tfm` file name) match.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the `\pdfmapline` primitive is even more convenient for me.

Comment: @Michael Ummels: The usage is just the same, but of course you've already discovered it.