# using `\pdfmapfile` on format creation

Tags: pdftex, format-files, font-map

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19469/running-pdftex-with-specific-map-). To quote the documentation:

> If you want to use a base map file
>   name other than pdftex.map, or change
>   its processing options through a
>   pdfTeX format, you can do this by
>   appending the `\pdfmapfile` command to
>   the `\everyjob{}` token list for the
>   -ini run, e. g.: `\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\pdfmapfile{+myspecial.map}}
>   \dump` This would always read the file
>   `myspecial.map` after the default
>   `pdftex.map` file.

I've tried to follow these instructions on my format creation, without success. I've placed the instruction at the end of the `pdftexconfig.tex` file, the way it used to work in the `pdftex.cfg` file, but I get the error

```
MLTeX v2.2 enabled
***pdflatex.ini
(/texmf/tex/initex/pdflatex.ini (/texmf/tex/initex/pdftexcf.tex
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.23 \everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob
                                        \pdfmapfile{+cmfonts.map}}
? x
```

Otherwise (without this addition at the end of the `pdftexcf.tex` file) the format creation goes without trouble. Anyone's guess why is this the case?

Caveat: I shortened the name of the configuration file as I am running on DOS; for that very same reason, I cannot afford to run `updmap`.

Comment: I could reproduce that error message by setting the catcode of `{` to something other than 1. Can you put ``\showthe\catcode`\{`` a line above that and report back, please?

Comment: It's `other` (12). I initialized the grouping catcodes and now it works. I knew I was missing something, but didn't quite figure it out.

Comment: I posted an answer, for the record (and because I'm procrastinating, hard :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was really strange-looking, at first, because `\the\everyjob` should expand to the contents of the `\everyjob` register, and then everything should work normally. The `Missing { inserted` message is clear: TeX was looking for a `{` (which is there, apparently), but didn't find it. The only way to have that is if `{` is not *actually* a `{`:

```latex
\everyjob{}
\catcode`\{=12
\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\pdfmapfile{+cmfonts.map}}
```

then the error message is the same:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   {
l.3 \everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob
                                       \pdfmapfile{+cmfonts.map}}
?
```

As GuM pointed out in the comment, INITEX does a barely minimal catcode setup, so that you can actually use it, and all other characters are initialised with catcode 12. The paragrah from *The TeXBook*:

> When `INITEX` begins, it knows nothing but TeX's primitives. All 256 characters are initially of category 12, except that `<return>` has category 5, `<space>` has category 10, `<null>` has category 9, `<delete>` has category 15, the 52 letters `A`...`Z` and `a`...`z` have category 11, `%` and `\` have the respective categories 14 and 0. It follows that `INITEX` is initially incapable of carrying out some of TeX's primitives that depend on grouping; you can't use `\def` or `\hbox` until there are characters of categories 1 and 2. The format in
>   Appendix B begins with `\catcode` commands to provide characters of the
>   necessary categories; e.g.,
>
> ```
> \catcode`\{=1
> ```

In fact, if you were to skip the next (assuming at least a catcode-2 `}`, for the sake of sanity) error message (`Too many }'s`), and you did `\showthe\everyjob` you would see: `{\pdfmapfile {+cmfonts.map`. Delightful :-)

With that message TeX is telling you that it found an illegal token (here, anything non-expandable, non-`{`) while looking for a `{`. The bottom two context lines show that it didn't even arrive at `\pdfmapfile`, so that isn't the problem, and `\everyjob` is empty (we made sure of that above). The only thing left is the `{` itself. The `<to be read again>` line means that the token `{` will be read again after the missing `{` is inserted (TeX is funny).

Moral: TeX's error message are *very* clear in meaning. You just have to think really hard to understand some.

---

For the sake of completeness, in order to restore the original `pdftex.cfg` functionality, you must add

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \global\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\pdfmapfile{+cmfonts.map}}
\endgroup
```

at the end of the `pdftexconfig.tex` file. Edit the rest of the configuration file according to your needs.

Comment: The fourth paragraph on p. 39 of _The TeXbook_ (a double dangerous bend paragraph, of course!) warns that “when `INITEX` [ = `tex --ini`] begins… all 256 characters are initially of category 12, except…” (a list of exceptions follows, that includes ``\``, which has category 0, and `%`, which has category 14, but does not include `{` and `}`, which, therefore, remain of category 12).  The paragraph continues: “It follows that `INITEX` is initially incapable of carrying out some of TeX’s primitives that depend on grouping”.  I think you should add this quotation to your answer.

Comment: @GuM Done. Thanks :-)

Comment: *Now* I can upvote! ;-D ;-D ;-D